# JavaScript: passing built-in objects' methods as callback functions

Tags: javascript, function, built-in

I've been working through [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)'s exercises and found out something I think is odd. I wrote a trivial array-flattening piece of code:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var out = arrays.reduce(function(acc, next){ return acc.concat(next); });
console.log(out);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So far so good. But that didn't seem pretty to me, so I rewrote it as:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var my_concat = function(acc, next){ return acc.concat(next); }
var out = arrays.reduce(my_concat);
console.log(out);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

It was better, but do we really need to introduce a function, be it anonymous or named, to do such a basic thing? `Array.prototype.concat.call`'s call signature is exactly what we need! Feeling smart, I rewrote the code again:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var out = arrays.reduce([].concat.call);
// → TypeError: arrays.reduce is not a function (line 2)
```

Well, that haven't turned out as I expected. The error message seemed cryptic to me.

I decided to investigate. This works:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
var my_concat = function(acc, next){ return [].concat.call(acc,next); }
var out = arrays.reduce(my_concat);
console.log(out);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

And this also works:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
arrays.my_concat = function(acc, next) { return [].concat.call(acc, next); }
var out = arrays.reduce(arrays.my_concat);
console.log(out);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

More tinkering in the console:

```
[].concat.call
// → call() { [native code] }
typeof [].concat.call
// → "function"
[].concat.call([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var cc = [].concat.call
cc
// → call() { [native code] }
typeof cc
// → "function"
cc([1, 2, 3], [4, 5])
// → Uncaught TypeError: cc is not a function(…)
```

And even this works:

```
Array.prototype.my_concat = function(acc, next) { return [].concat.call(acc, next); }
// → function (acc, next) { return [].concat.call(acc, next); }
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]].reduce([].my_concat)
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]].reduce([].concat.call)
// → Uncaught TypeError: [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]].reduce is not a function(…)
```

Is there something special about built-in functions like `.call`?

Comment: no. a bare `[].concat.call` would append all the arguments to the output, and [].reduce doesn't just pass the 2 arguments you use, it passes the index and the whole input array as well, so the output would be cluttered.

Comment: arrow function is the next best thing: `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]].reduce( (a,b)=>a.concat(b) )`... in theory, i would like to use natives as well, but if you have to bind(), re-apply(), or mangle prototypes, then i think a simple anon callback is more semantic, even if it's not as hard-core...

Comment: @dandavis Yeah, but aren't they mostly unsupported in the browsers yet?

Comment: works for me in chrome and firefox, not sure about others... (prod FF+ch btw, egads; the future is here)

Comment: @dandavis Arrow functions are not supported by mobile browsers, like, at all :-( I don't think it's ok to use in production something that is not supported by iOS/Safari — it's something like 50% of all traffic.

Comment: number vary, at my work safari is ~25% (college campus), but point taken. i'm just putting it out there for now (w/babel) or later (new every 2); watch that space. i think arrows work in FF+Ch mobile, but no iosIE (safari)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`call` is just a method that most functions inherit from `Function.prototype`. That is,

```
arrays.reduce.call === Function.prototype.call
```

The `call` method knows which function you want to call because that function is passed as the `this` value.

When you pass `call` as the callback, it will be called passing `undefined` as the `this` value. Since `undefined` is not a function, it throws. On Firefox I get this error:

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined
```

Instead, you could try one of these callbacks

```
Function.call.bind([].concat);
[].concat.bind([]);
```

However, the problem is that this won't work properly, because the callback is called with 4 arguments, not 2:

- previousValue
- currentValue
- currentIndex
- array

You want to get rid of the last two, so you need a custom function anyways.

However, these are not good approaches. Each time you call `concat`, it creates a new array. Therefore, if you want to flatten an array, you should call `concat` only once instead of per each item in the array:

```
[].concat.apply([], arrays); // this works
```

Comment: Thanks!
It's not obvious to me, though, why passing `[].my_concat` (the last code example in my question) works then :-(

Comment: I think I got this. That's because I don't rely on `this` inside of `my_concat`?

Comment: @DanilaSentyabov `[].my_concat` works because it ignores undesired arguments and calls `call` on a function.